# perl saving output of command with syntax highlighting

Tags: perl, terminal

I want to run a command in terminal and capture output so I'm using

```
my $output = `command`;
```

The problem is the command has syntax highlighting so then I do print later on I loose the syntax highlighting and instead get things such as

```
print $output;
```

Result

```
 ←[31merror←[39m ←[
```

How can I either get the command without syntax highlighting or somehow get the syntax highlighting to display on print.

Comment: Some commands (e.g. `grep`) have switches to turn the highlighting on/off.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to remove the ANSI color escapes from the shell output:

```
my $output = `command`;
my $output =~ s/\e\[[\d;]*m//g;
print "$output","\n";
```

If you want to remove all ANSI escape-sequences, then replace the regexp with:

```
s/\e\[?.*?[\@-~]//g
```